# "is it bad to be an extramural student" - is this question correct?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I have to choose a topic for my presentation and I would like to talk about being an extramural student. In my country there are opinions that these studies are worth less than full time studies so I want to show pros and cons of part-time studying. Is this quetsion correct? also I'm not sure if I should use "extramural" or "part-time" student/studies? To be precise, my lectures are on weekends so I'm not sure which word is more adequate for weekend studies?

Comment: "Extramural" literally means "outside the walls".  It applies to people who do not attend classes in person and has nothing to do with weekend studies.

Comment: Okay, so is there in english a better term that menas "weekend studies"? Is "part-time" term better than extramural?

Comment: "Part-time" is better.  Some universities may call these **[continuing education](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/continuing-education)** students, especially if the evening or weekend classes for students with full-time jobs are offered through an organized Continuing Education program that is separate from the program for full-time "traditional" students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "off-campus" might be more widely understood than "extramural".
The words "part-time" are in contrast to "full-time", which seems different from "on-campus" versus "off-campus".

If you are linking the two, you might ask "Is it bad to be a part-time, off-campus student?".